Зачем использовать static в коде на Си?
Чем код:
#include <stdio.h>

void counter() {
static int count = 0;
    printf("%d ", count++);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        counter();
    }
    return 0;
}

Отличается от кода:
#include <stdio.h>

int count = 0;

void counter() {
    printf("%d ", count++);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        counter();
    }
    return 0;
}

И там, и там, переменная создаётся один раз и используется во всём коде. Смысл использовать static?

В вашем конкретном примере разницы нет. Разница есть в проекте, который состоит из десятков файлов и живет много лет, переходя из одних рук в другие.

Главный смысл - что глобальная переменная торчит, как тополь на Плющихе :), и доступна всем и каждому, что не есть хорошо. Например, ее может чисто случайно (непреднамеренно) изменить другая функция.
А статическая переменная видна только в функции. И никакой ни злоумышленник, ни доброжелатель до нее не доберется...

Я бы добавил, что это собственно один из ключевых принципов ООП - инкапсуляция )

Скорее опасение пересечься по имени с такой же переменной уровня файла в другом файле (где-то в либе...) и свалиться на линковке в основном побуждает использовать слово static. Что же касается static переменных внутри функции, то это единственный способ сохранить данные функции между ее вызовами (т.е. тут мотивация совсем другая)
